# Having count in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Find the names of cities that hosts both SALES and TRANSPORT departments

For my oracle database have this table

i.) DEPTLOC

```
//DEPTLOC
CITY        DNAME
---------------------
NEWYORK       IT
NEWYORK     COMPUTER
LONDON      Science
LONDON      SALES
LONDON      TRANSPORT
```

For my SQL select statement

```
SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC
WHERE 
    DEPTLOC.DNAME='SALES' OR DEPTLOC.DNAME='TRANSPORT'
GROUP BY
CITY
HAVING COUNT(*)=2;
```

the output always display

```
no rows selected.
```

My output should be

```
DNAME
--------
LONDON
```

Comment: Where is `DNAME` field?

Comment: I'm guessing `DNAME` and `DEPARTMENT` are same, then the result wat you have got is rite.. as there is no row matching the where cluase

Comment: "no rows selected." is right as per your data and query !!

Comment: i changed the example. mind have a look.

Comment: It gives output. See [**this fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59425d/1). The problem must be something else.

Comment: It is giving the output..http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84cc8/1

Comment: The problem seems to be in your data. As the answer implies, your SQL works with the test data. So my guess is, there is another 'LONDON' row and with this your count(*) is greater than 2. Do you get a result using "having count(*)>=2" ?

Comment: Your query its ok, check this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbd83/2
Check your table data (like white spaces).

Your creation table script will help us to give you a better answer. Put here too a detailed table data.

Comment: it is correct.. I tried it also locally. consider implementing oracle patches.

Answer (score 1):

For things like this, I try to use a simple join to the same table.  First, I would have an index on the table by (City, DName).. then

```
select
      d.City
   from
      deptLoc d
         JOIN deptLoc d2
            on d.city = d2.city
           AND d2.dname = 'TRANSPORT'
   where
      d.dname = 'SALES'
```

It may look strange, but think about it.  The outer portion WHERE clause only cares about cities that have ONE of the qualifiers.  Why even count cities that dont even have that.  So, now the join.  Since you know the first qualifier on SALES is covered, re-join to the dept loc table again, but on the same city name AND the second instance is ALSO that of your 'TRANSPORT' component.  You will be surprised at how fast it would be, especially on a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
SELECT CITY FROM DEPTLOC
WHERE 
    trim(DEPTLOC.DNAME)='SALES' OR trim(DEPTLOC.DNAME)='TRANSPORT'
GROUP BY
CITY
HAVING COUNT(*)=2;
```

I think in your data you have some different chars like *space* or *new lines*

you can check it

Answer (score 0):

i think this could be a better query.

```
SELECT CITY 
FROM DEPTLOC
WHERE 
DEPTLOC.DNAME in ('SALES','TRANSPORT')
GROUP BY CITY
```